# What protection does Accident Investigation Authority Act really offer to airlines and pilots?

Tags: witnesses, testimony, aviation

ICAO's [Accident Investigation Authority Act](https://www.icao.int/SAM/Documents/2016-AIG-RECORDSPRO/Model%20AIG%20Act_%209%20Dec%202016%20.pdf) defines as one of the objectives to protect the evidence discovered during investigation from being used in court, presumably in order to obtain truthful information about the accident that otherwise people would rather hide:

> Final reports shall not be used as evidence in any court proceeding or in other proceedings related to apportioning blame or liability.

> No  finding,  cause  or  contributing  factor  determined  under  this  Act  shall  be  construed  as  assigning fault or determining civil or criminal liability.

However, airlines still get sued after an accident, so I wonder, what protection does this act really brings to the table.

If it helps, let's discuss an imaginary situation where a pilot didn't go through a proper drug test before flight, although the paperwork was done as if the test took place. After a hard landing, the test was not immediately done (medics were busy helping injured passengers) and when it was finally performed it came out negative.

Would it be safe for the pilot to tell the ICAO investigators about the skipped drug test, without the fear that this information will be used against him in court? Could the airline be sued for negligence based on such information?

Comment: Are you able to link the Act from which you quote, please?

Comment: @RickApe I included a link to a model from ICAO website.